# how can filter the value in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how can filter the value in firebase?

if I want to filter the value in firebase

Because the country values is variable, how can I do?

[image]

Below is my code

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
```

Could I filter the values?

Should I

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").child("country");   //???
```

=====================Update===================

now, I used this code, but I don't know why I can't get the country value in readPost function. Do I miss something?

```
firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference country_ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        country_ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                country = snapshot.child("country").getValue().toString();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

```
private void readPosts(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        Query query = reference.orderByChild("country").equalTo(country);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

I can get the country value in `country = snapshot.child("country").getValue().toString();`

but can't get in readPost function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries in Firebase are done like this:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts")
Query query = reference.orderByChild("country").equalTo("Australia");
```

You can then read the values matching this query with:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("Firebase", userSnapshot.getKey();
            Log.d("Firebase", userSnapshot.child("country").getValue(String.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
})
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) and [listening to value events for lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events). If you're new to Firebase, I also strongly recommend taking the [codelab for Android developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: I updated my context, could you check it? thx

Answer (score 0):

To get all countries of `"Posts"`-

```
private ArrayList<String> countryNameList;
private String countryName;
private TextView countryNameView;

   final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                countryName = ds.child("country").getValue().toString();
                countryNameList.add(countryName);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String s : countryNameList) {
                    stringBuilder.append(s + "\n");
                }
                countryNameView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I updated my context, could you check it? thx